# Bootstrap navbar collapse not formatting correctly

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the markup for a Bootstrap Navbar - this is generated from code-behind via a database - the problem is the right aligned items are being pushed under the rest of the menu items until the browser width is less than the left aligned items, then it acts normally.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Markup

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Application name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="MainNavBar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a title="Return to the home page" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl12&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Default&quot;, false, true))">Home</a></li>
                <li><a title="Ways to contact us" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl14&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Contactus&quot;, false, true))">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Latest News" href="#">News<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a title="Latest News" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl20&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;News/News&quot;, false, true))">News</a></li>
                    <li><a title="View Events" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl22&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;events&quot;, false, true))">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a title="Recommended Suppliers" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl24&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;external&quot;, false, true))">External</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Property for sale" href="#">Property<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a title="Property for sale" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl30&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Property/8&quot;, false, true))">For sale</a></li>
                    <li><a title="Property for lease" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl32&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Property/9&quot;, false, true))">For Lease</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a title="Local Information and services" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl34&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Content/10&quot;, false, true))">Local</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl37&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Secure/Landing/2&quot;, false, true))">Homeowners</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="https://oursite.com/hoa3_vendors/secure/landing/2" title="Login Section for Vendors Only">Vendors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

=============UPDATE================

This seems to work for the current setting, now it 'just' needs to be dynamic

```css
      @media only screen and (min-width: 790px) {
    .collapse {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-header {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
     .collapse {
        display: none;
     }

     .navbar-header {
        display: block;
     }
}
```

Comment: Too many items. Menu systems, Bootstrap's and most others, don't just determine when to adjust because there's too many links, you have adjust the menu breakpoint to accommodate your particular design. GetBootstrap.com customizer has a less variable you can change. Currently it's 768px, you can change it to 992 or some other value.

Comment: Hey Christina - thank you for your reply. The main issue I have is not knowing how many links will appear in the nav bar as it is dynamically generated for each site. Is there a mathematical equation I can use to adjust this on the fly? (Sorry I mainly write back end DB and WPF, from WinForms, so CSS is still something of a black art :-)

Comment: UPDATE - By default there are no .less files in a webforms project. Downloaded two from Bootswatch and found grid-float-breakpoint in variables.less - it was set to screen-sm-min which, as you pointed out, is 768px. I changed this to screen-md-min (992) and screen-lg-min (1200px) but has no effect - although I have no idea how the css files are wired up to the .less files - I just copied them into the same directory

Comment: The grid float breakpoint is in the customizer on the GetBootstrap.com site. You change it and then download your own customized file. If you use less, you compile it with a compiler.

Comment: Thank you - starting to make some sense now :-) Is there a way I can change this on the master page or via JavaScript? Script would the be best way to go in this instance.

Comment: If you have the skills you can do pretty much what you want, write an elaborate script to sniff out widths of the window, write css to load when the links don't fit the lines, etc., but never has CSS been able to do this and I've never seen a script do it either. Typically these things are addressed in the planning phase. If there is an unknown number of links use side navigation instead, for example.

Comment: I have scripts that vary the height of images based on the browser width, so I'm sure that is doable - the problem I'm having is finding the actual CSS value to change as grid-float-breakpoint doesn't seem to exist (in the CSS files that is)

Comment: that is a variable, it won't exist in the compiled css. You need to look up how to use LESS, grunt, etc, or use another compiler OR go to the customizer on the Getbootstrap.com site and change the var there and re-download. You can't change the media query via a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With many thanks to Christina and Michael for putting me on the right path.

Amending the existing CSS values would not have worked due to dynamic on the fly build of the menu. In the end I found this the best way to deal with the issue (where WidthSetting is defined at the time the menu items are being created). For menu items with a smaller link value it doesn't need to be run

```
Private Sub SetMenu(WidthSetting As Integer)
    Try
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){ ")
        SB.Append("$('body').append(")
        SB.Append("""<style>")
        SB.Append("@media only screen and (min-width: " & WidthSetting & "px) {")
        SB.Append(".collapse {")
        SB.Append("display: block;")
        SB.Append(" }")
        SB.Append(".navbar-header {")
        SB.Append(" display: none;")
        SB.Append(" }")
        SB.Append("}")
        SB.Append("@media only screen and (max-width: " & WidthSetting & "px) {")
        SB.Append(".collapse {")
        SB.Append("display: none;")
        SB.Append(" }")
        SB.Append(".navbar-header {")
        SB.Append(" display: block;")
        SB.Append(" }")
        SB.Append("}")
        SB.Append("</style>""); ")
        SB.Append("}); ")
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "SetMenu", SB.ToString, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim vError As New SendError
        vError.MailError(497, PageName, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This ran into an issue when the menu items got really long - in the collapsed state the last few menu items were out of range.

Here is the final (he says confidently) solution that allows for the overflow

```
 Private Sub SetMenu(WidthSetting As Integer)
    Try
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder
        SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){ ")
        SB.Append("$('body').append(")
        SB.Append("""<style>")
        SB.Append("@media (max-width: " & WidthSetting & "px) { ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-header { ")
        SB.Append("float: none; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-left, .navbar-right { ")
        SB.Append("float: none !important; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-toggle { ")
        SB.Append("display: block; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-collapse { ")
        SB.Append("border-top: 1px solid transparent; ")
        SB.Append("box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1); ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-fixed-top { ")
        SB.Append("top: 0; ")
        SB.Append("border-width: 0 0 1px; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-collapse.collapse { ")
        SB.Append("display: none !important; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-nav { ")
        SB.Append("float: none !important; ")
        SB.Append("margin-top: 7.5px; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-nav > li { ")
        SB.Append("float: none; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-nav > li > a { ")
        SB.Append("padding-top: 10px; ")
        SB.Append("padding-bottom: 10px; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".collapse.in { ")
        SB.Append("display: block !important; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-collapse.in { ")
        SB.Append("overflow-y: auto !important; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu { ")
        SB.Append("position: static; ")
        SB.Append("float: none; ")
        SB.Append("width: auto; ")
        SB.Append("margin-top: 0; ")
        SB.Append("background-color: transparent; ")
        SB.Append("border: 0; ")
        SB.Append("box-shadow: none; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a, .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header { ")
        SB.Append("padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a { ")
        SB.Append("color: #999; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, ")
        SB.Append(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus { ")
        SB.Append("color: #fff; ")
        SB.Append("background-color: transparent; ")
        SB.Append("background-image: none; ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append("} ")
        SB.Append("</style>""); ")
        SB.Append("}); ")
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "SetMenu", SB.ToString, True)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim vError As New SendError
        vError.MailError("481", PageName, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice job! I think string builder is my favorite i love it!

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the Bootstrap Documentation?

I think your issue is C mainly.

From Getbootstrap.com >

**Overflowing Content:**
Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:

A) Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.

B) Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using responsive utility classes.

C) Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the @grid-float-breakpoint variable or add your own media query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - could you give me an example of item C?

Comment: You just need to go through the css file and look at the media queries. Change the padding or the margin when it breaks to the second size. Shouldn't be hard. You could even just go to your page and press F12. Then change the css to see how it changes at the different sizes.

Comment: Can I just override with style at the header tags in the master page?

Comment: Yes you can, but it would be proper to change the actual css file. I know bootstrap is a huge file, but you need to spend time getting to know it.

Comment: Can you please upvote and check my answer as correct as this is the reason you're having issues.

Comment: Couldn't find the variable '@grid-float-breakpoint' (see screenshot) in bootstrap.css. As we will be using various Bootswatch files changing at the page level would be more advantageous - and as per comment to/from Christina really need to find a dynamic way of changing this

Comment: If you cant bother to upvote somebody's attempts to help you I cant bother to spend my time helping you. You asked what you did wrong. My answer told you what you did wrong.